# Get associated model's data in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

models/card.js

```
export default Model.extend({
  title: attr('string'),
  description: attr('string'),
  users: hasMany('user')
});
```

models/user.js

```
export default Model.extend({
  email: attr('string'),
  name: attr('string'),
  cards: hasMany('card')
});
```

app/routes/cards.js

```
model() {
  let user = this.store.find('user', 1); // here user is defined

  user.get('cards').then((cards) => {
    console.log(cards); // here user.get('cards') is undefined
  });
}
```

I want to get all the associated `cards` which are associated with the `user`.

Repo link: https://github.com/ghoshnirmalya/hub-client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.find()` returns a promise, so you should do something like this:

```
this.store.find('user', 1)
  .then(user => user.get('cards'))
  .then(cards => console.log(cards));
```

Comment: even if i do `this.store.find('user', 1)
  .then(user => {
    user.get('cards');
  })
  .then(cards => console.log(cards));
` it logs `undefined`. any idea why?

Comment: i've added a link to the repo.

Comment: Well, you miss a `return` in your code. `a => a` is *not* equal to `a => {a}` but equal to `a => {return a;}`.

Comment: i did this: `this.store.find('user', 1).then(user => { user.get('cards'); }).then(cards => {
  console.log(cards);
})`

Comment: Yeah exactly. Thats wrong. Either do `.then(user => user.get('cards'))` or `.then(user => {return user.get('cards');})`

Comment: i did this: `this.store.find('user', 1)
  .then(user => user.get('cards'))` which doesn't return any card although there are cards associated with that user in the database.

Comment: i also tried this: `this.store.find('user', 1)
  .then(user => user.get('cards'))
  .then(cards => {
    return cards;
  });` but without any result!

both of them are showing empty.

Comment: Then you definitely don't have cards for your user or don't give them to ember in a correct way. It [definitly works](https://ember-twiddle.com/bd2cf99ea20b4e4ce14322786683059d?openFiles=models.user.js%2C).

Comment: hey. it works. it was my bad that i wasn't sending the data properly from backend.